# MySQL query returning wrong row counts?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand data for a table that has over 3million rows, but the numbers don't add up. It is returning fewer rows than the table contains.

```
SELECT url FROM `archived_urls` GROUP BY url HAVING COUNT(url) > 1; -- rows returned: 29
SELECT url FROM `archived_urls` GROUP BY url HAVING COUNT(url) = 1; -- rows returned: 3078021
SELECT url FROM `archived_urls` GROUP BY url HAVING COUNT(url) < 1; -- rows returned: 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `archived_urls`;                               -- rows returned: 3078080
SELECT COUNT(url) FROM `archived_urls`;                             -- rows returned: 3078080
```

Math

```
29 + 3078021 + 0 = 3078050
```

Where are the remaining 30 rows? I even attempted to find them using `NOT IN` without success.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT COUNT(url) FROM archived_urls`,what's the result of it?

Comment: May you have some null values?

Comment: I checked for null values, this is not the case. I checked `COUNT(url)` and `COUNT(null)`, the problem still persists. Even if I hadn't the `NOT IN` query would have caught any leftovers surely?

Comment: The "missing" ones are your duplicates from your 1st query

Comment: I do yes, 29 rows as shown in my question, but I fail to see how that could cause said issue? I am still collecting all rows that are there and checking every possibility for `HAVING COUNT`, I could understand if I was selecting `DISTINCT` but I am not.

Comment: There are 29 urls with duplicates. So there are at least 2x29=58 rows for these urls. Why do you add only 29?

Comment: @forpas one url probably occures 3 times, not just twice

Comment: @Shadow this is why i say *at least*

Comment: I see. I thought `HAVING COUNT` returned x2 so all of the rows not just one for each that had duplicates. I have marked the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No records are missing, you are comparing apples with pears!

Your first query is:

```
SELECT url FROM `archived_urls` GROUP BY url HAVING COUNT(url) > 1; -- rows returned: 29
```

29 is the number of urls that occure more than once in your table, but not the number of records with these urls!

Check out the following query results:

```
SELECT url, count(url) FROM `archived_urls` GROUP BY url HAVING COUNT(url) > 1;
```

rows returned will still be 29, but if you add he values in count(url) column, you will get 31 more there.